# Back to the drawing board: Volume Switch App Starter

Tags: android

Alright as I have been asking the last couple days and inching closer and closer to the final outcome of this question:

Is it possible to use the volume (up / down) buttons to start an app?

Here is the code I am working with:

```
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
    Log.w("myApp", "LONG PRESS");
}
    //my code here 
return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
```

}
I am wondering what I am doing wrong. Nothing in the code is giving me errors, its just not running when I tell it to.
Note:
I am testing this on a live android if that helps out at all.

Any advice would be wonderful.

Comment: Please spend a few sentences explaining what you think "start an app" means.

Comment: I mean when I press and hold the volume key / button down for any extended time after the volume hits 0 it will "run" the app

Comment: OK, then please spend a few sentences explaining what you think "run the app" means. After all, your code above implies that your app is already running, so your definition of "run the app" is somewhat different, apparently.

Comment: How do I get the volume button to start the app instead of it having to be started already. That might be the better way of putting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use the volume (up / down) buttons to start an app?

No, sorry. You cannot use hardware buttons to start apps, with the exception of the CAMERA button (where it exists) or the MEDIA button (where it exists, typically on headsets). For those, you would register a `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest for their respective broadcasts, and bear in mind that those broadcasts are only sent out if the foreground activity does not consume the key event (e.g., music player pausing when the MEDIA button is pressed).

Comment: @a.kollar: I have no idea what sort of "alternatives" you are seeking.

Comment: Regrettably This app is special, in fact its special to the point I would not even call it an app but a service.It cant be just an icon on the home or else it kills the whole reason it exists. Does that by any chance change anything? I am not fully at liberty to discuss what we are trying to build.

Comment: @a.kollar: "Does that by any chance change anything?" -- you are welcome to create your own modded version of Android that somehow addresses this.

Comment: Or at least a modded version of the volume button code. -Thanks.